# Insertion in a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap, unique

I have a map of ticket and baggage, 
each ticket must be unique and must correspond to a position on the map
is it possible to change only the baggage (m_bagage-> second) without changing the key?

`std::unordered_map<Ticket, bagage> m_consigne;`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change keys in a map, they are `const`. Moreover keys in maps are unique. To change the value of an existing entry, given the key you can do

```
std::unordered_map<Ticket, bagage> m_consigne;
// add some entries
bagage b;
Ticket t;
m_consigne[t] = b;
```